# iAD implementation using self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

After watching an Apple WWDC video I decided to implement iAd using

```
@import iAd
...
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

which has been nice and simple and it displays test ads both in the simulator and on device.  The Apple vid I saw said that's all we have to do, but the Apple iAd doc site says we have to implement delegate methods to handle tapping, failing to load, network connectivity issues and that Apps that don't do so will be rejected.

That strikes me as confusing, not least because the implementation above doesn't add a protocol to the class so that the delegate methods can be implemented.

Does anyone know where the up to date docs are that implement iAds this new way ?  Or know authoritatively that we have to ignore what was said in the Vid and implement the delegate methods (though would they even be called?)?

Comment: My impression was the canDisplayBannerAds = yes solution was the absolutely no frills version. It gives you no control the placement of your banner. I tried it, and it actually interfered with how my app handles rotations. So, unless you have a straight out-of-the-box implementation, it's probably not a good choice, and you'll have to implement the more complex stuff for control.

Comment: Funnily enough, the screen the ad appears on is so simple that this implementation of iAd and the app actually play nicely together.  Crazy.

Comment: Not "simple" -- well-written! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. There doesn't appear to be a way to assign a delegate unless you use the old method (which defeats the purpose). My specific issue was an error I was getting when on another screen without Ads, which said that I wasn't handling the didFailToReceiveAdWithError and hadn't set a delegate. To fix this specific issue I simply enabled and disabled ads as the view appeared and disappeared. Like so:

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    //  Setup iAd Banner Ads

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear: animated];

    //  Disable iAd Banner Ads

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = NO;
}
```